# How to assign foreign key value from views instead of template and save into database in Django

Tags: django, view

I want to get the bank_Id and save as foreign key in AddressInfo model directly from view and rest of the AddressInfo fields value should be taken from template.

This is my view where I take **bank_id** from **bank_update View** and pass into **address_bank_create** view

```
def address_bank_create(request, bank_id):
    bank_detail = Bank.objects.get(id=bank_id)
    form = AddressInfoForm(request.POST or None)
    # I want to save to bank_id along with template data
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('impex:bank_update', args=[bank_id]))
    else:
        form = AddressInfoForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'bank_detail': bank_detail
    }
    return render(request, "impex/addressinfo_create.html", context)
```

This is my ModelForm of **AddrssInfo** Form and **Bank** Form

```
class AddressInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    office_house_no = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Office / House No'}))
    street = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Street'}))
    land_mark = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Land Mark'}))
    city = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter City'}))
    state = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter State'}))
    country = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Country'}))
    complete_address = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'maxlength': '1000', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Complete Address'}))
    bank = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    buyer = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = AddressInfo
        fields = [
            'office_house_no',
            'street',
            'land_mark',
            'city',
            'state',
            'country',
            'complete_address',
            'bank',
            'buyer',
        ]

class BankForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Bank Name'}))
    ad_code = forms.CharField(required=False,
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter AD Code'}))
    remark = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'maxlength': '500', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Your Remarks'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Bank
        fields = [
            'company_name',
            'ad_code',
            'remark'
        ]
```

My Template contains the basic django form code

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

My Model contains Bank as parent and AddressInfo as child. AddressInfo have foreign key of bank.

```
class AddressInfo(models.Model):
    # primary_uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    office_house_no = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Office House No")
    street = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    land_mark = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    complete_address = models.TextField(max_length=800, verbose_name="Complete Address", blank=True, null=True)
    bank = models.ForeignKey("Bank", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Bank", blank=True, null=True)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey("Buyer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Buyer", blank=True, null=True)


class Bank(models.Model):
    # primary_uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True,editable=False)
    slug_name = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    ad_code = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name="AD Code", blank=True, null=True)
```

URL Pattern

```
path('bank-dashboard/', views.bank_dashboard, name='bank_dashboard'),
path('bank-recent/', views.bank_recent, name='bank_recent'),
path('bank-create/', views.bank_create, name='bank_create'),
path('bank-view/<int:pk>/', views.bank_view, name='bank_view'),
path('bank-update/<int:pk>', views.bank_update, name='bank_update'),
path('bank-delete/<int:pk>/', views.bank_delete, name='bank_delete'),

path('bank-address-info-create/<int:bank_id>', views.address_bank_create, name='address_bank_create'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use the form instance.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.bank_id = bank_details.id
    form.instance.save()
```